# ¿Qué es el directorio de trabajo actual, cómo lo determino y cómo lo cambio?

Tags: python

## Promesa

La respuesta a esta pregunta va a responder las siguientes preguntas:

- ¿Por qué la apertura de un archivo que SI existe da error de archivo no encontrado (file not found)?,
- ¿Por qué, al hacer la creación de un archivo y luego este no se encuentra en la computadora o no lo encuentran otros scripts?
- ¿por qué operaciones de apertura, creación, eliminación de archivos si funcionan cuando ejecuto el script desde el entorno de desarrollo, pero no cuándo lo invoco desde otros scripts, en otros entornos, la línea de comandos, la computadora del usuario final, el servidor, etc.?
- ¿por qué operaciones de apertura, creación, eliminación de archivos si funcionan cuando ejecuto el script desde otros scripts, en otros entornos, la línea de comandos, la computadora del usuario final, el servidor, etc., pero no funcionan cuando lo ejecuto desde el entorno de desarrollo?
- ¿Por qué al leer un archivo desde python me da un contenido diferente del que puedo ver al abrir yo el archivo en el bloc de notas, excel u otra herramienta?

Y otras.

## Pregunta

**¿Qué es el directorio actual de trabajo, cómo lo determino y cómo lo cambio en un script python?**

De la que se desprenden estas preguntas relacionadas que me gustaría fueran respondidas:

- ¿En qué afecta a mi script el directorio de trabajo en que se encuentre?
- ¿Cuál es el directorio de trabajo por defecto al ejecutar python?
- ¿Qué son las rutas absolutas y relativas?
- ¿Por qué esto es importante cuándo quiero abrir, crear o borrar archivos desde mi script?

**Aviso**:
Escribo esta pregunta con el objetivo que sea una especie de guía definitiva y respuesta canónica a una serie de preguntas que se dan en python debido a desconocimiento o confusión sobre este tema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta respuesta es bastante larga para los estándares de StackOverflow, si luego de leer dos o tres líneas de un concepto te das cuenta que ya lo conoces, salta sin pena a la siguiente sección. Si luego te está costando entender explicaciones que se basan en las secciones anteriores, siempre puedes devolverte a ellas, leerlas y releerlas, buscar otras referencias o jugar con un poco de código, hasta comprender el concepto detrás de las definiciones.

## Introducción

Comenzaré diciendo que conceptos como *directorio de trabajo* o *directorio actual de trabajo*, *directorio raíz*, *ruta absoluta* y *ruta relativa* a un archivo o carpeta no son exclusivos de python, sino que vienen del sistema operativo.

Hasta la fecha, todos los sistemas operativos para los que he programado asocian a cada *proceso* en ejecución un *directorio actual de trabajo*, por lo que considero que es un concepto importante y que te servirá independientemente del lenguaje en el que estés programando.

Para responder, voy a ir explicando estos importantes conceptos de una manera detallada:

## Directorio raíz

El artículo [Directorio raíz](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directorio_ra%C3%ADz) de la wikipedia lo define como:

> el directorio raíz es el primer directorio o carpeta en una jerarquía. Contiene todos los subdirectorios de la jerarquía.

- En windows, los directorios raíz son todos los de las unidades, como

  - `C:\`
  - `F:\`

  La raíz de las rutas UNC, tal como

  - `\\MiOtraPC\`
  - `\\UnServidor\`

  Rutas de acceso DOS, tal como:

  - `\\.\C:\`
  - `\\?\C:\`
  - `\\.\Volume{b75e2c83-0000-0000-0000-602f00000000}\`
- En sistemas basados en Unix/Linux, la raíz del sistema de archivos, `/`.

## Ruta Absoluta

Conocemos como *ruta absoluta* a aquella que identifica a un archivo o carpeta dentro del *sistema de archivos*, partiendo de una *ruta raíz*. Ejemplos:

- Windows

  - `C:\users\juan\miarchivo.txt`
  - `F:\datos`
  - `\\UnServidor\UnaCarpeta\OtraCarpeta\UnArchivo.dat`
  - etc.
- Unix/Linux

  - `/home/juan/miarchivo.txt`
  - `/var/log/syslog`

## Ruta Relativa

Es una ruta que ***no*** comienza por un directorio raíz, tal como:

- Windows

  - `miarchivo.txt`
  - `C:datos\juan.txt`
  - `SubCarpeta1\SubCarpeta2\Archivo.dat`
  - `SubCarpeta1\SubCarpeta2`
  - `..\archivo.txt`
  - `\archivo.txt`
- Unix/Linux

  - `miarchivo.txt`
  - `subcarpeta1/subcarpeta2/archivo.dat`
  - `subcarpeta1/subcarpeta2`
  - `../archivo.txt`

Estas rutas se llaman relativas, porque deben concatenarse al final de una ruta absoluta para saber exactamente el archivo o la carpeta que representan. Usualmente esta es la ruta del directorio de trabajo del proceso donde se utilice la ruta relativa.

## Directorio trabajo

Extrayendo lo más relevante de [Directorio de trabajo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directorio_de_trabajo) de la wikipedia:

> el directorio de trabajo de un proceso es un directorio de un sistema de archivos jerárquico ... También es llamado el directorio actual de trabajo (CWD por sus siglas en inglés: current working directory) o simplemente directorio actual.

> Cuándo un proceso se refiere a un archivo usando un nombre de archivo simple o una ruta relativa (a diferencia de una ruta absoluta que parte de un directorio raíz, la referencia es interpretada como relativa al directorio de trabajo del proceso.

Vemos entonces que, en todo momento, cada proceso tiene un *directorio actual*, que no es más que una ruta dentro del sistema de archivos.

El interprete de python es un proceso que corre dentro del sistema y es el que se encarga de *interpretar* y ejecutar el código que escribamos dentro de nuestros scripts y dentro de cualquier script que importemos. En esta idea, nuestro script, que corre dentro de ese proceso, también tiene un *directorio actual*.

Cuando se pide al sistema operativo realizar una operación con un archivo, como abrirlo o crearlo, y se le envía una ruta relativa, el sistema operativo concatena esta ruta al directorio actual del proceso que solicita dicha operación.

Así, si lanzamos

```
archivo = open('miarchivo.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
```

Y nuestra ruta actual es `/home/jcastillo/src` el sistema operativo intentará abrir el archivo `/home/jcastillo/src/miarchivo.txt`

Otros ejemplos

| ruta relativa al archivo | ruta actual | ruta absoluta al archivo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| miarchivo.txt | / | /miarchivo.txt |
| miarchivo.txt | c:\ | c:\miarchivo.txt |
| miarchivo.txt | c:\users\jcastillo | c:\users\jcastillo\miarchivo.txt |
| x/y/z.txt | / | /x/y/z.txt |
| x/y/z.txt | /home/jcastillo/src | home/jcastillo/src/x/y/z.txt |
| x\y\z.txt | c:\ | c:\x\y\z.txt |
| x\y\z.txt | c:\users\jcastillo | c:\users\jcastillo\x\y\z.txt |
| ../miarchivo.txt | / | error |
| ../miarchivo.txt | /home/jcastillo/src | home/jcastillo/miarchivo.txt |
| ..\miarchivo.txt | c:\ | error |
| ..\miarchivo.txt | c:\users\jcastillo | c:\users\miarchivo.txt |
| \miarchivo.txt | c:\ | c:\miarchivo.txt |
| \miarchivo.txt | c:\users\jcastillo | c:\miarchivo.txt |

Estamos muy acostumbrados al concepto de directorio actual al utilizar la línea de comandos. De hecho, el *prompt* usualmente nos muestra la ruta a ese directorio actual y sabemos muy bien construir rutas relativas para llegar a los archivos o carpetas que nos interesan al lanzar comandos.

Lo que quizás nadie te explicó, hasta hoy, es que este directorio actual no es una particularidad del proceso de la línea de comandos (el shell), como `cmd.exe` y `powershell.exe` en windows, o `/bin/bash` en Linux, sino que **todos los procesos** tienen un directorio actual.

## Determinar el directorio actual de mi script

Para determinar el directorio actual de tu script, puedes valerte de la función [`getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) de la biblioteca [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html). Esta función retorna una cadena con la ruta al directorio actual.

```
import os

diractual = os.getcwd()
print(diractual)
```

Mostrará en la consola cuál es el directorio actual del proceso dónde está corriendo mi script (como se dijo antes, el interprete de python). La salida va a ser una ruta, tal como:

```
/home/jcastillo/src
```

O como:

```
C:\Users\jcastillo\src
```

## Cambiar el directorio actual del proceso

También podemos cambiar el directorio actual del proceso valiéndonos de la función [`chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) de la biblioteca [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

A esta función le podemos pasar una ruta absoluta, o una ruta relativa (al que es hasta el momento de la llamada el directorio actual del proceso).

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir("/var/log")
print(os.getcwd())
```

produce una salida como:

```
/home/jcastillo/src
/var/log
```

mientras que:

```
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir("..")
print(os.getcwd())
```

```
/home/jcastillo/src
/home/jcastillo
```

## Pyton, la ruta de mi script y el directorio actual

Llegados a este punto, esperaría que la idea esté ya bastante clara, sin embargo no dejo en el tintero afirmar que: El directorio actual no tiene por qué ser la misma ruta donde está almacenado el archivo que contiene mi script. De hecho, regularmente no lo es.

Algunos IDE's, por defecto, establecen la ruta actual a la misma ruta donde está el script. En mi opinión, esto solo produce confusión en los programadores novatos.

## Ruta actual por defecto de un script Python

No existe tal cosa como una *ruta default* cuando se ejecuta un script python.

Todos los interpretes de línea de comandos que conozco, al lanzar un *comando externo*, hacen que dicho proceso inicie con la ruta actual establecida a la misma ruta actual del interprete de comandos.

Es decir, si yo lanzo el comando:

```
jcastillo@devUbuntu:~/src$ python3 so/593021/so593021.py
```

La ruta actual con la que va a iniciar mi script va a ser `/userjcastillo/src`, aunque el script se encuentre en la ruta `/userjcastillo/src/so/593021`.

De hecho, para lanzar un proceso en el sistema operativo, uno de los parámetros que se le pasa a la función que lo lanza es el directorio actual inicial del proceso. Si se le pasa una ruta en blanco, usualmente el directorio inicial se establece a la misma carpeta donde se encuentra el ejecutable del proceso que se lanza. Mira la documentación de [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) y [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), que te permiten lanzar nuevos procesos, aceptan el parámetro `cwd` (*current working directory*), que es la ruta con la que se inicializará el directorio actual de los sub-procesos lanzados.

Esto también es importante, porque debemos recordar que Python es un **lenguaje interpretado** y, como tal, nuestro script no es *el proceso* que se ejecuta a nivel del sistema operativo. Lo que se ejecuta a nivel del sistema operativo es el *interprete de Python*. Así que, si se diera el caso de crear un proceso de Python para interpretar un script y no le diéramos al sistema operativo ninguna ruta actual de inicio, la ruta sería la del ejecutable de Python, por ejemplo `/usr/bin`.

Si lanzas aplicaciones o tu propio script desde un *acceso directo*, tanto en Windows como en Linux, puedes establecer el directorio actual con el que inicia el proceso. En windows busca el campo *"Iniciar en"* (*"Start in"*).

En Linux, si tu distribución/sistema de ventanas utiliza las especificaciones de [desktop-entry](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) (como Ubuntu, que usa gnome), puedes usar la llave `Path` para indicar la ruta actual inicial para el proceso.

## Tener una ruta actual que varía es algo bueno, no es algo malo

Si te adaptas a la idea, puedes explotar esto, es lo que todo mundo que programa comandos hace.

Imagina que lanzas tu script desde diferentes rutas y que, según la ruta actual, el script va a buscar sus datos en una sub-carpeta `datos` de ese directorio, entonces, haces algo como:

```
c:\users\jorge\Documentos>python3 c:\scripts\procesardatos.py
c:\users\juan\Documentos>python3 c:\scripts\procesardatos.py
```

Ya procesaste los datos que se encuentran en las carpetas:

```
c:\users\jorge\datos
c:\users\juan\datos
```

Con exactamente el mismo script.

## Conocer la ruta de mi script

Si definitivamente necesitas conocer la ruta de tu script, por ejemplo, para acceder a recursos externos que deben acompañarlo, puedes obtenerla valiéndote de la pseudo-referencia [`__file__`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__file__-a-special-variable-in-python/), que siempre el nombre del script dónde se coloque. Si quieres obtener solo el nombre de la carpeta, puedes valerte de [`os.path.dirname()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)

```
print(os.getcwd())
print(__file__)
print(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Puede producir una salida como esta:

```
/home/jcastillo/src
/home/jcastillo/src/so/593021/so593021.py
/home/jcastillo/src/so/593021
```

Ya con esta, puedes construir con la ayuda de [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) la ruta absoluta de estos recursos y con esa ruta realizar las operaciones como apertura de archivos, etc.

```
print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "datos\datos.csv")
```

En mi caso va a imprimir lo siguiente sin importar cual sea la ruta actual del interprete.

```
/home/jcastillo/src/so/593021/datos/datos.csv
```