# Problema al leer txt con Python en terminal de VSC

Tags: python, archivo, vscode

estoy teniendo un problema al querer leer un archivo txt en Python desde VS Code

El código

```
archivo = open('hola.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')

lineas = archivo.readlines()

print(lineas)
```

El código es simple, agarro el archivo 'hola.txt' y le digo que sea de lectura, con codificacion 'utf-8'.
El archivo hola.txt tiene escrito dentro 'hola mundo'.
En VS Code lo que esta haciendo al mostrarmelo en la terminal python, es devolverme una lista vacia, cuando debiera devolverme ["hola mundo"]
Si lo ejecuto desde la cmd si me regresa la lista con su contenido.

Me ayudan a identificar donde esta el problema? Se me hace que el problema esta en la terminal del vscode pero no se como corregirlo.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que estás leyendo el mismo archivo desde VSCode y desde la terminal? Coloca `import os` y luego un `print(os.getcwd())` para comprobar esto.

Comment: Gracias por la información. Mi area de trabajo es un arbol de carpetas ejemplo (CARP/CARP1..CARP2) y el codigo con el archivo de texto se encuentran por ejemplo en CARP1. Al hacer getcwd vi que no ingresa a CARP1, se queda en CARP. Ahora agregando a mano el resto de la direccion que faltaba pudo leerlo! Gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué es el directorio de trabajo actual, cómo lo determino y cómo lo cambio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593072/qu%c3%a9-es-el-directorio-de-trabajo-actual-c%c3%b3mo-lo-determino-y-c%c3%b3mo-lo-cambio)

Comment: si usas `open` deberias usar `close`  al final.