# Error al importar un modulo

Tags: python, mvc

Holaa, tengo que importar este modulo al dao y me sale que el modulo conex no existe, cuando está y al pincharlo si me lleva a este, no entiendo, si alguien pudiera ayudarme:(([image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal y como está tu pregunta, es difícil poder reproducir el problema con exactitud, sería útil que proporciones el código que te da problemas en formato de texto, en vez de imágenes, de esta manera, será más fácil que alguien pueda brindarte ayuda. Además, sin datos más técnicos como la configuración del entorno, es muy difícil poder saber con exactitud la causa del problema. Puedes leer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: mi proyecto es crear un crud para una empresa automotriz en modelo mvc, pero al momento de importar el conex me arroja el siguiente mensaje en los dos modulos del dao:
 "c:/Users/blood/Downloads/Ev3 parte 1/ev/dao/dao_empleado.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\blood\Downloads\Ev3 parte 1\ev\dao\dao_empleado.py", line 1, in <module>
    from conex import conn
ImportError: cannot import name 'conn' from 'conex' (C:\Users\blood\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\conex\__init__.py)

Comment: así mismo al abrir la ruta me lleva al __init__.py del conex y en el conn  me lleva al archivo con mi clase conex.

Comment: Te aseguraste de haber instalado bien el módulo? Si es un módulo nativo, debería de importarse sin problemas, sino prueba usando `pip install nombre_del_modulo`. Por otra parte, si el módulo es local, necesitarás importarlo de la siguiente manera: `from subcarpeta import nombreDelArchivo`. Recuerda que Python busca los módulos en los directorios especificados en la variable de entorno PYTHONPATH y también en el directorio actual.

Comment: revise, en el caso de los otros modulos, son creados por mi, al momento de iniciarlos me arroja el error de que no existe un modulo con ese nombre, pero al buscar la ruta si me lleva a el.

Comment: Tal y como sugiere el editor, cuando creas un paquete, se usan rutas relativas. No puedo explicarlas en un comentario. Pero tiene pinta de que es la solución

Comment: No me acuerdo bien ahora y estoy algo flojo con lo de crear paquetes, pero creo que para acceder al directorio raiz, se usa ..

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué es el directorio de trabajo actual, cómo lo determino y cómo lo cambio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593072/qu%c3%a9-es-el-directorio-de-trabajo-actual-c%c3%b3mo-lo-determino-y-c%c3%b3mo-lo-cambio)

Comment: @JorgeLuis en este caso, se trata de la carpeta raiz del paquete. No del directorio de trabajo. Pero gracias por el aporte c:

Answer (score 0):

Si el módulo "conex" es una biblioteca externa o personalizada, debes asegurarte de que esté instalado correctamente en tu entorno de desarrollo. Puedes verificar si el módulo está instalado ejecutando el comando pip list en la línea de comandos y buscando el nombre del módulo en la lista de paquetes instalados.