# (Python) Problema al reconocer archivo.txt en terminal en VS Code

Tags: python, vscode, txt

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
try:
    fh = open(fname)
except:
    print('File cannot be opened:', fname)
    quit()
lst = []
for line in fh:
    lst += line.split()
```

...

Aunque el código sigue, el problemas está en que en la terminal en VS Code no me reconoce o no encuentra el archivo.txt que se encuentra en la misma carpeta que el archivo.py que muestro. Sin embargo, cuando corro el programa con el debugger de VS Code me lo reconoce perfectamente y da el output esperado :S. ¿Alguna idea sobre cómo solucionar esto? Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué es el directorio de trabajo actual, cómo lo determino y cómo lo cambio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593072/21)

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. En el comentario anterior dejé un link a una pregunta y respuesta que te serán útiles para resolver este problema. Un saludo y, de nuevo, bienvenido.

Comment: El problema radica en que al ejecutar el script desde la terminal de VS Code, el directorio actual puede ser diferente del que contiene tanto el archivo de script como el archivo de texto. Para solucionarlo, puedes verificar el directorio actual de trabajo con os.getcwd() y luego especificar la ruta completa del archivo usando os.path.join() para asegurarte de que el archivo pueda ser abierto correctamente.