# Error icono en el ejecutable python pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

[image: error]

Estoy teniendo este error cuando ejecuto el .exe
el comando que utilizo para crear el ejecutable es

> pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "Alarma.wav;." --icon=icono.ico
> main.py

el icono y el audio se encuentran en la misma carpeta que el archivo main.py, voy a dejar el fragmento de codigo donde se pone el icono por si es de ayuda.

```
class ObjectDetectionApp:
    """Clase para la aplicación de detección de objetos."""
    def __init__(self, root):
        """Inicializa la aplicación."""
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Segurity Chamba")
        self.root.geometry("825x520")
        self.root.iconbitmap("icono.ico")
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué es el directorio de trabajo actual, cómo lo determino y cómo lo cambio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593072/qu%c3%a9-es-el-directorio-de-trabajo-actual-c%c3%b3mo-lo-determino-y-c%c3%b3mo-lo-cambio)

Comment: @jachguate Siendo sincero creo que ahora tengo mas dudas que antes de igual manera lo voy a releer

Comment: @jachguate Okay, ahora entendí, debo tener los archivos necesarios  en la misma carpeta del ejecutable, pero existe alguna forma de poner los archivos necesarios dentro del ejecutable para que no tenga la necesidad de poner esos dos archivos extra, como seria el .ico y el sonido? es decir que vengan incluidos dentro del script por decirlo de alguna manera

Comment: Creo que no has comprendido del todo. Puedes poner estos dentro de la carpeta del ejecutable, es cierto, pero luego puedes iniciar con otro directorio como actual y tampoco los encontrará. Diría que, en tu caso, puedes poner estos archivos en cualquier lugar siempre y cuando puedas construir una ruta absoluta para llegar a ellos.

Comment: Por otro lado, en realidad el "ejecutable" que genera pyinstaller lleva todo dentro, incluyendo el ícono y el sonido, pero tiene que ponerlo en el sistema de archivos primero para lanzar tu script. pyinstaller no es un compilador que produzca un ejecutable que tenga la lógica de tu script. Es un _"envoltorio"_ que se lleva el entorno de ejecución, incluido el interprete de python, y lo lanza, tal cual, en otro equipo.

Comment: @jachguate puede hacer lo de la ruta absoluta y funciono, lo que no logro comprender ahora es lo ultimo que me estas diciendo, como podrás notar estoy aprendiendo sobre esto, entonces como recomendarías que cree un ejecutable, para que este sea funcional y no tenga que llevar los archivos por separado? desde ya muchas gracias por tu tiempo. quizá si podría poner la"ruta" donde se guarda el icono y el audio dentro del ejecutable podría solucionar ese problema, pero es posible?

Comment: Si necesitas crear un ejecutable real, no puedes hacerlo con python, que es un lenguaje interpretado. Debes usar un lenguaje compilado, tal como C, C++, Delphi, incluso C#, etc. este es un resultado de google donde te puedes informar: https://blog.makeitreal.camp/lenguajes-compilados-e-interpretados/

Comment: @jachguate Muchas gracias, voy a estar revisandolo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ¿Cómo funciona PyInstaller?

Primero de todo, la forma en la que Pyinstaller crea el ejecutable es mediante un procedimeinto conocido como *freezing* (congelado). A grandes rasgos, lo que hace es empaquetar el interprete de Python, las bibliotecas necesarias, tu aplicación y todos los recursos (imágenes, archivos de datos, etc) de forma que pueda ejecutarse en otro sistema sin el intérprete y las dependencias instaladas.

Al crear un ejecutable con la opción `--onefile` todo se empaqueta en un solo archivo comprimido junto a un bootloader. Cuando se ejecuta, el bootloader crea una carpeta temporal llamada `_MEIxxxxxx` en la localización que el sistema operativo provee para ello (donde xxxxxx es un número aleatorio) y descomprime todo en ella.

### Resolver rutas adecuadamente

Cuando se crea un ejecutable de esta forma, las rutas a los archivos externos que nuestra app usa quedan obviamente rotas. No obstante el bootloader también almacena en `sys._MEIPASS` la ruta absoluta a la carpeta temporal creada (en el caso de `--onefile`). Ver [Run Time Information (PyInstaller Doc)](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html?highlight=sys._MEIPASS#run-time-information).

Por lo tanto, debemos resolver la ruta de forma dinámica en tiempo de ejecución en base a `sys._MEIPASS`. Si queremos que la ruta se resuelva también adecuadamente cuando la app no se ejecuta desde el ejecutable de PyInstaller, por ejemplo cuando la ejecutamos localmente mientras la desarrollamos, debemos adaptar la ruta para cada caso. Típicamente esto se hace creando una función global para procesar las rutas a los recursos de la aplicación, por ejemplo (tomada de [esta respuesta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44352931/7131499)):

```
import sys
import os

def get_resource_path(relative_path):
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

### Especificar a PyInstaller que recursos debe incluir

Además de resolver la ruta de forma adecuada a un recurso, se debe indicar a PyIstaller que archivos debe incluir en el ejecutable. Esto lo puedes hacer de dos formas:

- Al ejecutar pyinstaller mediante el [argumento `--add-data`](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/man/pyi-makespec.html?highlight=add-data#what-to-bundle-where-to-search), de la forma `--add_data="<ruta_archivo>:<destino>`", por ejemplo:

  ```
    pyinstaller app.py --onefile --add-data="icono.ico:."
  ```
- Mediante el [archivo .spec y el atributo `Analysis.datas`](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html?highlight=spec#spec-file-operation)

---

Por ejemplo, imaginemos que tenemos esta estructura de archivos:

```
test
|_app.py
|_resources
   |_python.png
```

con nuestro script `app.py`:

```
import sys
import os
import tkinter as tk


def get_resource_path(relative_path):
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


root = tk.Tk()
img = tk.PhotoImage(file=get_resource_path('resources/python.png'))
tk.Label(root, image=img).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Creamos el ejecutable con:

```
$ cd ruta/a/carpeta/test
$ pyinstaller app.py --add-data="./resources/python.png:./resources" --onefile
```

o si queremos simplemente añadir todo el contenido de la carpata `resources`:

```
$ pyinstaller app.py --add-data="./resources:./resources" --onefile
```

Comment: Tengo una duda es necesario los paths como decis? yo lo puse de esta manera:
(pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "Alarma.wav;." --icon=icono.ico main.py)
 ya que los archivos se encontraban en el mismo lugar que main.py

Comment: Use la carpeta `resources` solo para ejemplo, en tu caso es correcto lo que haces, siendo explícito es lo mismo que `--add-data "./Alarma.wav;.`".

Comment: Ahora me fui de casa, en cuanto vuelva lo pruebo y te comento el resultado, gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: Ok, por cierto, seguramente será un typo al crear el mensaje, pero es `"Alarma.wav:."` no   `"Alarma.wav;."` (el separador es dos puntos, no punto y coma).

Comment: Funciono, muchas gracias.