# conectar python a db2 ibm error en dll

Tags: python

por favor su ayuda, soy nuevo en el lenguaje y tengo un programa en python que conecta a db2 al que le entrego la ruta de las dll de esta forma:(debido a que tenia problemas y esta solución busque en la web)

```
import os
os.add_dll_directory('C:/Users/pmendezo/AppData/Local/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/clidriver/bin')
import ibm_db
...
 dsn = "DRIVER={{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}};DATABASE=DB2BCH;HOSTNAME=xxxx;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxxxx;"
conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")
... etc
```

Cuando compilo el programa no tengo ningún problema, conecta y devuelve información de la base datos en DB2 sin inconvenientes, pero cuando hago el ejecutable del programa y lo abro aparece el siguiente error:
*ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ibm_db: No se pudo iniciar la aplicación; la configuración en paralelo no es correcta. Consulte el registro de eventos de la aplicación o use la herramienta sxstrace.exe de la línea de comandos para obtener más detalles.*

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda. muchas gracias.

Lei en otro foro que si utiliza la libreria sqlalchemy tambien entrega el mismo error.
No tengo acceso a cambiar el PATH del computador, como he visto en otras soluciones.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! hay un boton [edit] ahi.. usalo...

Comment: Si estas creando un exe con PyInstaller u otro freezer la ruta absoluta a las dll no funcionará, para empezar son rutas locales a una carpeta en tu PC... debes incluir esas dependencias explícitamente en tu exe y establecer la ruta de forma adecuada en el código de ser necesario. Mírate [Error icono en el ejecutable python pyinstaller](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/616551/15089) y [esta respuesta del sitio en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63073952/7131499).

Comment: Hice el .exe con add data y copie la carpeta a la del .exe, la crea en ' _internal/clidriver ' y tiene todos los archivos adentro, pero al ejecutar el exe dice que "dll load failed when importante ibm_db".

El error me marca en esta linea donde importo ibmo_db:

os.add_dll_directory('c:/users/pato/appdata/local/programs/python/python310/lib/site-packages/clidriver/bin')

import ibm_db

podra ser que debo copiar los archivos dentro de bin a otra carpete del programa .exe como por eje la carpeta dist..? gracias