# Error al ejecutar un programa empaquetado (.exe) con pyinstaller

Tags: python, mysql, xampp, pyqt5, pyinstaller

les comento que estoy intentando crear un proyecto en Python, el programa cuenta con una base de datos con MySQL desde XAMPP y cuenta con interfaces desde PyQT5 con interfaces .ui. El programa debe de ser ejecutable y que pueda funcionar en diferentes equipos.

Mi problema es que a la hora de pasar el programa a .exe con `pyinstaller --onefile Pantalla13.py`. Es que cuando ejecuto el programa ya empaquetado (el programa exe) en la carpeta `dist` me arroja el siguiente error en una consola:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "pantalla13.py", line 1803, in <module>
File "pantalla13.py", line 38, in __init__
File "PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 241, in loadUi
File "PyQt5\uic\Loader\loader.py", line 66, in loadUi
File "PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 1020, in parse
File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1203, in parse
File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 557, in parse

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ingreso.ui'
[10728] Failed to execute script 'pantalla13' due to unhandled exception!
```

Este es un fragmento del código principal, exactamente en la configuración de la ventana de ingreso:

```
class VentanaLogin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Cargar la interfaz de carga desde el archivo .ui
        loadUi('ingreso.ui', self)
        #posicion del click del mouse
        self.click_position = None
        #botones para ingresar y salir
        self.bt_ingresar.clicked.connect(self.authenticate_admin)
        self.line_contra.returnPressed.connect(self.authenticate_admin)
        #self.bt_ingresar.clicked.connect(self.authenticate_user)
        self.bt_salir.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())


        # botones para acceder a nuestras redes sociales
        self.bt_face.clicked.connect(self.facebook)
        self.bt_twitx.clicked.connect(self.x)
        self.bt_inst.clicked.connect(self.instagram)
        self.bt_you.clicked.connect(self.youtube)


        self.main_window = Sistema()  # Crear instancia de VentanaPrincipal
        self.ventana_registro = VentanaRegistro() # Crear instancia de VentanaRegistro

        # Ocultar VentanaPrincipal e VentanaRegistro inicialmente
        self.main_window.hide()
        self.ventana_registro.hide()

        # Estas dos lineas se encargan de ocultar la barra de titulo
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        #El boton bt_registrar se encarga de dirigirnos a la interfaz con el nombre VentanaRegistro
        self.bt_registra.clicked.connect(self.show_registro_window)
        #El checkbox sirve para ocultar o visualizar la contraseña
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.toggle_visibility)

        
        

        self.gripSize = 10
        self.grip = QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self)
        self.grip.resize(self.gripSize, self.gripSize)

        self.frame.mouseMoveEvent = self.mover_ventana

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        rect = self.rect()
        self.grip.move(rect.right()- self.gripSize, rect.bottom() - self.gripSize)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.click_position = event.globalPos()

    def mover_ventana(self, event):
        if self.isMaximized() == False:
            if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                self.move(self.pos() + event.globalPos() - self.click_position)
                self.click_position = event.globalPos()
                event.accept()

    def toggle_visibility(self, state):
        # Cambiar la propiedad echoMode del LineEdit de la contraseña según el estado del CheckBox
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            self.line_contra.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Normal)
        else:
            self.line_contra.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

    def facebook(self):
        # Abrir el enlace en el navegador predeterminado
        url = QUrl("https://www.facebook.com/irvin.gonzalezmateos.1?mibextid=9R9pXO")
        QDesktopServices.openUrl(url)
    
    def x(self):
        # Abrir el enlace en el navegador predeterminado
        url = QUrl("https://x.com/Walter_Obrian10?t=WhIzT0911PDcWg_1PAvrZA&s=08")
        QDesktopServices.openUrl(url)

    def instagram(self):
        # Abrir el enlace en el navegador predeterminado
        url = QUrl("https://www.instagram.com/harry12_wells/")
        QDesktopServices.openUrl(url)
    
    def youtube(self):
        # Abrir el enlace en el navegador predeterminado
        url = QUrl("https://youtube.com/@harrisonwells713?si=qTlAXsNN7pvWCW32")
        QDesktopServices.openUrl(url)

    def show_registro_window(self):
        # Mostrar la VentanaRegistro cuando se presiona el botón "Registrar"
        self.ventana_registro.show()
        self.hide()

    def authenticate_admin(self):
    # Obtener el usuario y la contraseña ingresados
        usuario = self.line_usuario.text()
        contraseña = self.line_contra.text()
    
        if usuario != '' and contraseña != '':
        # Verificar si el usuario y la contraseña coinciden con la base de datos
            if self.main_window.base_datos.autenticar_admin(usuario, contraseña):
            # Obtener la ruta de la imagen asociada a ese usuario
                imagen_binaria = self.main_window.base_datos.obtener_imagen_perfil(usuario)
                self.main_window.set_usuario(usuario,imagen_binaria)
                
                self.show_main_window()
                self.line_usuario.clear()
                self.line_contra.clear()

            else:
            # Mostrar un mensaje de error si la autenticación falla
                self.label_error.setText("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos!!")
        else:
            self.label_error.setText("Hay espacios vacíos!!")



    def show_main_window(self):
        self.hide()  # Ocultar la pantalla de carga
        self.main_window.show()

    # Obtener el nombre de usuario
        usuario = self.line_usuario.text()
        

    # Obtener la imagen almacenada en la base de datos
        imagen_binaria = self.main_window.base_datos.obtener_imagen_perfil(usuario)

        if imagen_binaria:
        # Si hay una imagen para el usuario, mostrarla en el QLabel
            pixmap = QPixmap()
            pixmap.loadFromData(imagen_binaria)
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.main_window.label_imag.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            self.main_window.label_imag.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.main_window.label_imag.show()
            self.main_window.bt_delete.show()
            self.main_window.bt_animar.hide()
        else:
            self.main_window.bt_animar.show()


    def showEvent(self, event):
        # Sobrecargamos el evento showEvent para realizar la animación al mostrar la ventana
        super().showEvent(event)
        self.fade_in_animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"windowOpacity")
        self.fade_in_animation.setDuration(1000)  # Duración de la animación en milisegundos
        self.fade_in_animation.setStartValue(0.0)
        self.fade_in_animation.setEndValue(1.0)
        self.fade_in_animation.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    splash_screen = VentanaLogin()
    
    splash_screen.show()
   
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Espero que puedan apoyarme a solucionar este error del ejecutable y gracias por la atención.

Comment: Los archivos .ui es un recurso más, debes agregarlo explícitamente para que se incluya en el exe y si usas `--onefile` debes además resolver las rutas de forma adecuada, mírate esta pregunta: [Error icono en el ejecutable python pyinstaller](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/616551/15089), aunque se trata de un icono y tkinter el problema y su solución es el mismo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué es el directorio de trabajo actual, cómo lo determino y cómo lo cambio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593072/qu%c3%a9-es-el-directorio-de-trabajo-actual-c%c3%b3mo-lo-determino-y-c%c3%b3mo-lo-cambio)