Como corregir el error tras compilar mi proyecto en python
Tras compilar mi proyecto con los directorios incluidos obtengo el siguiente error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Script2.py", line 6, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: '../Data/intrusos'

Adjunto parte de mi código que refleja la línea 6, agradecería vuestra ayuda comunidad.
dataPath = '../Data' 

archivos_intrusos = os.listdir(dataPath +'/intrusos')  # usa esta seccion para reconocer a los intrusos 
archivos_mov = [os.path.splitext(archivo)[0] for archivo in archivos_intrusos if archivo.endswith(".MOV")]


Hola Jesús, bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿A que te refieres con "compilar"? Python es un lenguaje interpretado, no se compila, se ejecuta en un intérprete. ¿El error es al ejecutar el script/proyecto? ¿O estas creando un .exe a través de de un "freezer" como pyInstaller y es este ejecutable el que genera el error?

Hola FJSevilla!!
Estoy creando un archivo. exe, cuando ejecuto el script opera con total normalidad. Pero cuando hago doble clic sobre el archivo .exe me salta el error.

Mírate esta pregunta:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/616551/error-icono-en-el-ejecutable-python-pyinstaller/616576#616576 y mi respuesta a ella a ver si te aclara lo que te está pasando y la solución.

Revise la documentación, la estructura que tengo es la siguiente, cuando abro un terminal sobre Codigo y ejecuto el Script2.py todo esta ok, no obstante me gustaría saber si para crear el .exe requiero colocar el código de app.py en la carpeta raíz Proyecto-Final, estoy empleando python -m PyInstaller --onefile app.py
Proyecto-Final/
│
├── Codigo/
│   └── Script2.py
│
├── Data/
│   ├── CENTRO EDUCATIVO
│   ├── INTRUSOS
│   └── MODELOS
