Directorio de trabajo en Python
Instale Python 3.12 hace unos días y cada vez que trato de escribir un programa al guardarlo me abre la carpeta donde instale el programa. Tengo creado en "documentos" de Windows una carpeta para almacenar los programas/ejercicios, y cada vez me toca buscarla manualmente para que el archivo quede guardado donde corresponde.
¿Hay alguna manera de indicarle cual es el directorio de trabajo por defecto sin que afecte al resto del IDLE?.
Gracias.

Python es el interprete de scripts. No existe tal cosa como guardar un programa en Python, pues en principio no tiene nada para editarlos. Seguro instalaste un IDE que incluye soporte para Python y tu pregunta sea sobre ese IDE, ¿cómo se llama? Pregunto, porque hay muchos y la respuesta sería específica para el que uses.

@jachguate, no soy el OP, pero calculo que se refiere al IDLE (notese la L extra), un IDE que se puede instalar junto a Python y está programado en Tkinter, funcionando a través de un módulo de la librería estandar llamado "idlelib". Aún así, una aclaración del op para dar luz vendría bien :)

He descargado el Python 3.12 de la página oficial de python, que incluye el shell script y la posibilidad de crear y guardar archivos con extensión *.py. Este tipo de archivo es el que me gustaría poder guardar por defecto en la carpeta "documentos" de Windows, en vez de en el directorio de en el directorio donde instale Python.

En este enlace de esta misma web (el cual es un poco extenso):
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593072/qu%c3%a9-es-el-directorio-de-trabajo-actual-c%c3%b3mo-lo-determino-y-c%c3%b3mo-lo-cambio
explica con mucho detalle todo lo relacionado con directorios de trabajo, rutas absolutas, relativas, etc.
Así como resumen a groso modo, la respuesta sería no, no se puede indicar un directorio de trabajo por defecto. La razón de esto es que cada script almacena consigo su propia ruta de trabajo que es igual al directorio en el que se encuentra, en tu caso, si el script está en el directorio
C:\Users\nombreuser\Documentos, ese es el directorio de trabajo de ese / esos scripts.
Para una información mucho más completa y extensa, lee el link que te he dejado al principio.
